# remap gnu screen "other" window selection

Tags: gnu-screen, remapping, escape-characters

In my .screenrc file, I have:

```
escape \034\034
```

This remaps ^a to ^\. This works for switching windows when specifying the window number, such as ^\0 or ^\1 but the 'other' command is not available, as seen by showing the help (:help). (The 'other' command is ^a,^a by default, and switches to the last used window.) How do I get the "other" command back while keeping my remapped escape key?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should rebind it:

```
bind \034 other
```